# Chrome browser is not launching when launched on selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following configuration :

- Webdriver version : 3.3.0
- Chrome version : 56
- Chromedriver version : 2.24
- OS Version : Windows 10

The exception I am facing is given below. I am quite new to selenium so not sure what could be the possible reason. I tried executing the same code with severla versions of chromedriver but with no luck

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 45496
Only local connections are allowed.
Mar 13, 2017 8:27:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:11:07 -0800'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-CU1N4JE', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 0f4877e9d55cf1682ea6b45d0196319a
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:835)
    at pkg_1302_02.Cl_1303_02.main(Cl_1303_02.java:19)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using?

Comment: The first thing you should always do is make sure your browser and drivers and the most recent versions.

Comment: Hi i upgraded to the latest version of chrome(57) and the chromedriver version is 2.28.455520, however i still get an exception

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of chrome driver. Using latest chrome drive will solve the issue. Download latest chrome driver from [Link to download Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.)

Comment: I still get the same exception though

Comment: Capabilities [{message=unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 4ced6565d1d7fe9581145d4a08bfbe58